# Django show ManyToMany field of model using ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, html, django, django-orm

I have a "parent" model containing different fields, and one of them is a ManyToMany field refering to another model (that in turn, has several fields).

I would like to display a ModelChoiceField containing the name of the ManyToMany objects that the "parent" model has.

models.py

```
class Media(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    ident = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    media = models.ManyToManyField(Media)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

To do so, at views.py I have:

```
l = Parent.objects.all().order_by('name')
for parent in l:
    if parent.name == unicode(request.session['current_parent']) 
        break
m = forms.ModelChoiceField(parent.media.all(), widget=forms.Select())
return render_to_response('tab.html', {'media_list':m})
```

But what I see rendered at my html is this sentence: `<django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x03294570>`

How should I do it to render the list properly?

Comment: Use model forms for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just display a form field on its own. It has to actually be part of a form, which you must instantiate before passing it to the template.

Also note that your method for getting the parent is *horribly* inefficient: you instantiate every single Parent in the database, just to get one. You should query it directly.

```
class ParentForm(forms.Form):
     media = forms.ModelChoiceField(Media.objects.none(), widget=forms.Select())
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         parent = kwargs.pop('parent')
         super(ParentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['media'].queryset = parent.media.all()

def my_view(request):
    parent = Parent.objects.filter(name=request.session['current_parent'])
    form = ParentForm(parent=parent)
    return render_to_response('tab.html', {'media_form': form})
```

Alternatively, it might be easier to just pass the parent object to the template and then construct the select box manually:

```
 <select name='media'>
 {% for media in parent.media.all %}
     <option value='{{ media.ident }}'>{{ media.name }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
 </select>
```